# How to write JUnit test case for JMS client in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, publish-subscribe, activemq-artemis, jmstemplate

I have to write unit test for my producer and consumer in ActiveMQ Artemis. I'm using publish-subscribe model. How do I write the test cases for both?

The following is my producer code:

```java
@Component
public class OrderPublisher {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private static final Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderPublisher.class) ;

    @Value("${jsa.activemq.topic}")
    String orderTopic;

    public void sendOrderData(String orderData) {
        log.info("sending message to queue");
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(orderTopic,orderData);   
    }
}
```

This is my application properties for producer:

```
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
jsa.activemq.topic=bt-order-queue

spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=localhost
spring.artemis.port=61616
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=admin
```

This is my code for consumer which is in a separate project.

```java
@Component
public class OrderSubscriber {
 
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderSubscriber.class);

    @JmsListener(destination = "${jsa.activemq.topic}")
    public void receiveMessage(String order) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println("order data from queue::"+order);
    }
}
```

Properties file for consumer:

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=localhost
spring.artemis.port=61616
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=admin
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
jsa.activemq.topic=bt-order-queue
```

This what I'm trying for prodcuer:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

class ApplicationTests {    
    
    @Autowired
    OrderPublisher publisher;   
    
    @Rule
    public EmbeddedActiveMQResource resource = new EmbeddedActiveMQResource();
     
    //ActiveMQProducerResource producer = new ActiveMQProducerResource(resource.getVmURL(), "bt-order-queue");
    //ActiveMQConsumerResource consumer = new ActiveMQConsumerResource(resource.getVmURL(), "bt-order-queue");
     
    @Before
    public void before() {
        resource.start();
        resource.createQueue("bt-order-queue");
    }
    
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {       
        publisher.sendOrderData("test");
        
        ClientMessage cons=resource.receiveMessage("bt-order-queue", 100000);
        System.out.println("cons::"+cons.toString());       
    }
}
```

But as I'm lacking information on how to write it, I'm just trying to figure out a way

Comment: my question is how to write junit test case for both producer method and the consumer method.
I have edited my original post accordingly

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JustinBertram i have updated what i've tried for consumer.
What i'm not able to understand is how does the embedded server work.
And if any proper sample material is available for this

Comment: @JustinBertram is there any sample from which i can refer. I'm completely lost over here